# Segmentation fault (core dumped) - this error is shown only sometimes and I cannot seem to fix it

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump, fault

I have seen many different forums here and elsewhere and I cannot seem to find what is wrong wit my code in particular. I have no pointers, so it can only be something with the arrays that I am using - I tried to change them and see what happens, tried to write down what is happening and when but still the error shows sometimes. I only know it has to do with memory and accessing something I am not supposed to, but cannot identify the problem - possibly more of them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int number;
    int test;
    while ((test = scanf("%d", &number)) == 1){
            if (number == 0){
                    return 0;
            }
            if (number < 0){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Chybny vstup!\n");
                    return 100;
            }
            printf("Prvociselny rozklad cisla %d je:\n", number);
            if (number == 1){
                    printf("%d", number);
            }
            else{
                    bool prime[number+1];
                    for(int i = 0; i <= number; i++){
                            prime[i] = true;
                    }

                    for(int j = 2; j * j <= number; j++){
                            if (prime[j] == true){
                                    for (int multiples = 2; prime[j * multiples] <= number; multiples++){
                                            prime[j * multiples] = false;
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                    int result[50];
                    int multipliers[50];
                    for(int i = 0; i <= 50; i++){
                            result[i] = 0;
                    }
                    for(int i = 0; i <= 50; i++){
                            multipliers[i] = 1;
                    }
                    int counter = 0;
                    for (int test=2; test <= number; test++){
                            if (prime[test]){
                                    if (number % test == 0){
                                            number /= test;
                                            result[counter] = test;
                                            counter++;
                                            while(number % test == 0){
                                                    multipliers[counter-1]++;
                                                    number /= test;
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                    for (int c = 0; c < counter; c++){
                            if (multipliers[c] > 1){
                                    printf("%d^%d", result[c], multipliers[c]);
                            }
                            if (multipliers[c] == 1){
                                    printf("%d", result[c]);
                            }
                            if (result[c+1] > 1){
                                    printf(" x ");
                            }
                    }
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    if (test == 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Chybny vstup!\n");
            return 100;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: My suggestion would be to run your executable with `gdb`. Enter in whatever values you've recorded that are causing a segfault, and `gdb` will halt execution. You can use `bt` to see the trace of where things went wrong, and check the value of variables to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Try valgrind: http://www.valgrind.org/

Comment: @user3121023 yes, I saw this one and fixed it but the same problem is there anyway.

Comment: @user3121023 thanks - yes that was also an issue - now it seems to work fine for number under 7-8 digits, however I would need it to work for more as well. It generally has problem with bigger numbers and always gives that error

Comment: @user3121023 and what could be done about that? I have no experience with th stack?

Comment: Note that if you `#include <stdbool.h>` you do not need to define your own `bool`. Since you are using VLAs you must have C99 or newer, so this header is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should always do, is write your program piecewise, and verify it works after completing each feature, before moving to a new one. Since you then test each feature you are implementing separately, you know that any bugs are most likely in the feature you implemented last.

In your case, this problem immediately pokes my eye:

```
for (int multiples = 2; prime[j * multiples] <= number; multiples++){
    prime[j * multiples] = false;
}
```

Here, you test `prime[j * multiples] <= number`, i.e. compare the *flag* to a number.  Because the late flags are zeroed till the end of the array, `j*multiples` will go out of bounds of the `prime[]` array, and eventually crash your program.

The test should be `j * multiples <= number`, of course.

Because I work one feature and one problem at a time, I don't know if that is the only problem your code has.  Finding out is your task.  If I were you, I'd write the code piecewise, perhaps sprinkling `printf()`s when testing, to verify each part works, so that I could rely on code I had already written, and concentrate on the part at hand, and do steady progress with minimal frustration.

---

There have been quite a few questions regarding Eratosthenes sieves recently. I've always found it useful to implement an abstract, dynamically allocated sieve type, and simple accessor/modifier functions to change it.  Because there should only be one sieve in a program, it can be described using global variables:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* This is the number of bits in an unsigned long.
   The exact value is floor(log(ULONG_MAX + 1)/log(2)),
   but the following definition will be correct on all
   modern architectures: */
#define  ULONG_BITS  (sizeof (unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT)

/* Prime sieve, with a flag for zero and each odd integer,
   one bit per flag. */
static unsigned long  *sieve = NULL;

/* Largest positive integer within the sieve. */
static uint64_t        sieve_max = 4;

/* Number of unsigned longs allocated and initialized in the sieve. */
static size_t          sieve_words = 0;

/* Function to discard the sieve, if no longer needed. */
static inline void  sieve_free(void)
{
    free(sieve);        /* free(NULL); is safe, and does nothing. */
    sieve       = NULL;
    sieve_max   = 4;    /* Since 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 give built-in answers */
    sieve_words = 0;
}
```

The initial `sieve_max` is 4, because our `is_prime()` test function treats 0, 1, 2, and 3 prime, and all larger even integers non-prime anyway; that means that integers 0 through 4 are always known to our `is_prime()`:

```
/* Return 1 if number is prime according to sieve,
          0 if known composite/not prime. */
static inline  int is_prime(const uint64_t  number)
{
    /* 0, 1, 2, and 3 are considered prime. */
    if (number <= 3)
        return 1; /* Prime */

    /* All larger even integers are not prime. */
    if (!(number & 1))
        return 0; /* Not prime */

    /* Outside the sieve? */
    if (number > sieve_max) {
        fprintf(stderr, "is_prime(): %" PRIu64 " is outside the sieve!\n", number);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    {
        const uint64_t       half = number / 2;
        const size_t         w = half / ULONG_BITS;
        const unsigned long  m = 1uL << (half % ULONG_BITS);

        /* The flag for odd number is (number/2)th.
           half / ULONG_BIT  is the word where bit
           half % ULONG_BIT  is in.
           Return 0 if the bit is set, 1 if clear. */
        return !(sieve[w] & m);
    }
}
```

We can very easily grow the sieve, defaulting all new flags to "not prime":

```
static void sieve_upto(const uint64_t  max)
{
    /* Number of words needed for (max+1)/2 bits. */
    const uint64_t nwords = 1 + max / (2 * ULONG_BITS);
    const uint64_t nbytes = nwords * (uint64_t)sizeof (unsigned long);
    const size_t   words = (size_t)nwords;
    const size_t   bytes = words * sizeof (unsigned long);
    unsigned long *temp;

    /* Already covered by the current sieve? */
    if (sieve_max > max)
        return;

    /* We need to be able to handle max+1,
       and neither bytes or words should overflow. */
    if (max >= UINT64_MAX ||
        (uint64_t)words != nwords || (uint64_t)bytes != nbytes) {
        fprintf(stderr, "sieve_upto(): %" PRIu64 " is too high a maximum.\n", max);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Do we already have all the bytes we need? */
    if (words == sieve_words) {
        sieve_max = max;
        return;
    }

    /* Allocate/reallocate. Note that realloc(NULL, size)
       is equivalent to malloc(size), so this is safe
       even if 'sieve' is NULL. */
    temp = realloc(sieve, bytes);
    if (!temp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory for a sieve up to %" PRIu64 ".\n", max);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    sieve = temp;

    /* Clear the new words to all zeros. */
    memset(sieve + sieve_words, 0, (words - sieve_words) * sizeof (unsigned long));

    sieve_max   = max;
    sieve_words = words;
}
```

Finally, we need a function that will mark a number composite (not prime):

```
static inline void not_prime(const uint64_t  number)
{
    /* Primality is internally handled for 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4. */
    if (number <= 4)
        return;

    /* All larger even numbers are internally handled. */
    if (!(number & 1))
        return;

    /* Outside the sieve? */
    if (number > sieve_max) {
        fprintf(stderr, "not_prime(): %" PRIu64 " is outside the sieve!\n", number);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    {
        const uint64_t       half = number / 2;
        const size_t         w = half / ULONG_BITS;
        const unsigned long  m = 1uL << (half % ULONG_BITS);

        /* Half is the bit index in sieve[].
           half / ULONG_BITS  is the word containing the bit
           half % ULONG_BITS  that needs to be set. */
        sieve[w] |= m;
    }
}
```

The sieve of Eratosthenes construction I shall leave to you; my intent is to only show how a relatively efficient (that is, balancing memory use and run time) sieve for odd positive integers can be created and managed, using dynamic memory management.

([Verifying](https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html) that a simple Eratosthenes sieve finds all 455,052,511 primes less than 10,000,000,000 takes less than 90 seconds, and that it finds all 203,280,221 32-bit primes takes less than 30 seconds, on my laptop, using a single core, and the above functions. For higher ranges, it is better to use a windowed sieve. Note that prime counting functions do not consider 0 and 1 prime, unlike the above `is_prime()`.)

Comment: Thanks,

yes that was an issue that I noticed, however it still does not work after fixing that part, but with large numbers 6-7 digits and more it crashes on this 

for(int i = 0; i <= number; i++){
                            prime[i] = true;
                    }

Comment: @lll: Your prime array is a local variable in `main()`, so it is allocated on stack. It is typical for stack allocations to be limited to a few megabytes.  Global variables can be larger, but they too tend to be limited; the limit is just higher. You need to dynamically allocate the sieve.